# Rails + Cloudinary Gem - How to add rounding step to cl_image_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, view-helpers

I'm using the `cloudinary` gem and `cl_image_tag` helper method to display my images.

```
<%= cl_image_tag(picture.image, :width => :auto, :dpr => :auto, :responsive_placeholder => "blank") %>
```

As you can see, I'm adding the `:width => :auto` option in the helper method. This helper will create a link of this sort

```
<img data-src="http://res.cloudinary.com/travelcrumbs/image/upload/dpr_auto,w_auto/v1470821928/hero%20image/footsteps.jpg" class="cld-responsive">
```

The `:width => :auto` option creates a `w_auto` request in the created URL. 
This way an image with appropriate (depending on the container) width is being requested from the cloudinary CDN. But I would like to change the rounding step to 200px (so that it only requests a different image every 200px.) and need to get a `w_auto:200` request in the URL.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width` parameter should be set to "**auto:200**". This can be done by switching to something like:

```
<%= cl_image_tag(picture.image, :width => "auto:200", :dpr => :auto, :responsive_placeholder => "blank") %>
```

Comment: Cool apparently, I still had an older gem that didn't support this option. Thanks for your answer